# macOS Mojave: Android studio: the emulator process for AVD was killed

Tags: java, android, macos

I want to try android auto emulator, so I am trying to download it from the AVD manager, but after several times. I then find even my phone emulator can not be opened, with this error: `The emulator process for AVD was killed`

I have tried to upgrade my android studio, reinstall it, uncheck platform-tools and check in AVD manager, replace emulator folder, you name it, I have tried them all, but not working.

After I try to start emulator with command line, error like below:

```
dyld: Symbol not found :_vmnet_shared_interface_name_key
Referenced from ..../qemu-system-x86_64 (which was built for Mac OS X 
11.1)
```

Comment: Update your OS X

Comment: I have used back to android studio 4.1 RC1, although when start the avd, still a popup "unable to locate adb", but the virtual device is able to start. So I think upgrade android studio brings this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the latest emulator can not work on the mojave(Mac OS X
10.14).

Solution:

1. Install emulator by sdk manager, and create vitual devices by svd
2. Try to download an older version (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip)
3. Unzip the file, then replace your android emulator folder(usually `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`) with the folder that you just unziped.
4. go to your emulator folder `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`, list all the virtual devices `./emulator -list-avds` then try to open one of the virtual devices by `./emulator @YOUR_DEVICE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and **The simple solution is:**

**Try to install lower API Level of virtual device**, so for example if you are trying to use API Level 30, change to API Level 27 and see if it works

[image]

so you need to

- click on **AVD Manger** icon on top right corner of your Android studio, (or navigate to Tools then AVD Manager)
- then click on **Create Virtual Device** button
- select a device (such as Pixel 2) and click next
- try API LEVEL 27 (Oreo)

Hope that can fix your issue same as it fixed mine

Comment: Thank you buddy. I have solved this problem by upgrading both Mac OS and android studio. Now it's working like a charm